# R Data.Table Merge Based on Effdt

Tags: r, merge, data.table

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get started merging a transactional data table to a domain data table.  I'd like to merge the distributions data table below to the department data table so I know the name of the department involved when the transaction occurred.  What I'd ultimately like to end up with after the merge is a data table like such:

```
PayeeName  Department     PaymentDT   Amount
Bob        Modified Name  2016-01-01  5
Tracy      Payables       2015-01-01  34
Tom        Postal         2015-01-01  87
```

Here is some sample data that is similar to the format I am working with.

```
library(data.table)
dtDistributions <- data.table(PayeeName = c("Bob", "Tracy", "Tom"),
                          Department = factor(c("H229000", "H135000", "H047800")),
                          Amount = c(5, 34, 87),
                          PaymentDT = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01")))

dtDepartments <- data.table(Department = factor(c("H229000", "H229000", "H229000", "H135000", "H047800")),
                        EffDT = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2012-01-01", "1901-01-01", "1901-01-01", "1901-01-01")),
                        Descr = c("Final Name","Modified Name","Original Name","Payables","Postal"))
```

Comment: Your sample data (`dtDistributions`) holds exactly the information you said you wanted to end up with. Can you clarify what exactly you are having trouble with?

Comment: No, the final output should have the department name, and not the department number.  dtDistributions does not currently have department name, only department number.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a solution, but it doesn't use data.table functionality so I hesitate to call this an answer to my original question but wanted to share in case it helps anybody else.  I ended up using the sqldf library which allows you to write SQL syntax against existing dataframes.  I'm more than willing to accept a data.table answer as my actual dataset is quite large and I imagine it would be a lot faster than my sqldf implementation.

```
library(sqldf)
joinString <- "SELECT A.PayeeName, B.Descr, A.PaymentDT, A.Amount
            FROM dtDistributions A, dtDepartments B
            WHERE A.DEPARTMENT = B.Department
            AND B.EffDT = (SELECT MAX(ED.EffDT)
                            FROM dtDepartments ED
                            WHERE B.Department = ED.Department
                            AND ED.EffDT <= A.PaymentDT)"

finalDT <- data.table(sqldf(joinString))
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code since 3 departments names were tied to the same department number. So I first altered your code there as follows:

```
dtDistributions <- data.table(PayeeName = c("Bob", "Tracy", "Tom"),
                              Department = factor(c("H229000", "H135000", "H047800")),
                              Amount = c(5, 34, 87),
                              PaymentDT = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01")))

dtDepartments <- data.table(Department = factor(c("H229000", "H229001", "H229002", "H135000", "H047800")),
                            EffDT = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2012-01-01", "1901-01-01", "1901-01-01", "1901-01-01")),
                            Descr = c("Final Name","Modified Name","Original Name","Payables","Postal"))
```

I then proceeded to use the following command to merge the data tables:

```
dtDistributions = merge(dtDistributions, dtDepartments[, .(Department, Descr)])
```

You can always rename the columns and reorder them later. But this should do the merge trick.

Comment: I wanted H229000 to have three different names.  The dtDepartments data table is a domain table, so it will have the history of all the different names a department number can go through in it's lifecycle.  Since the original transaction for Bob in H229000 happened on 2016-01-01, that means it occurred after department H22900 was renamed from "Original Name" to "Modified Name" but before it it was changed to "Final Name".  Does that make sense?

Comment: Aaah got it. Other than the clunky way of creating a separate column identifier that says Department name based on date parameters and then combining it, I'm not too sure about it! Sorry!